# Getting video width height from RTP Packets or Rtsp Server

Tags: directshow, h.264, rtsp, rtp, rtsp-client

I have to get stream video [which is from rtsp server] width and height.

Third party servers give the following info at RTSP DESCRIBE REQUEST:

**One RTSP server give me width-height**

```
Server Response:

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
....

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length: 376

a=x-dimensions:1280,1024 // GET WIDTH HEIGHT

....
```

> **a=x-dimensions:1280,1024**

**But the other does not give me width/height info....** It seems that it supports ONVIF...

```
Server Response:


RTSP/1.0 200 OK

x-Accept-Dynamic-Rate: 1
... 
Content-Length: 625
... 
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96

i=Video channel in H264 VBR format

a=mpeg4-esid:201

a=control:trackID=0

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032;....

m=application 0 RTP/AVP 107

i=ONVIF metadata

a=control:events

a=sendonly

a=rtpmap:107 vnd.onvif.metadata/90000
```

**Anyway/method to get stream width-height?**

Comment: How to do RSTP resolution selection while making server request???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Width and height can be extracted from the H.264 sequence parameters set, which is *usually* part of the fmtp line of the SDP in the DESCRIBE response. See this [helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream) by cipi.

Comment: I think that in more often resolution/dimensions are not available via X-Dimensions, however they are available with parameter sets provided with SDP. Still, the most reliable source of the information, and sometimes it is the only source, is the bitstream itself and parameter sets embedded there. BTW there is nothing actually preventing RTSP source to change resolution right on the fly.