# VLC Player Keeps Resizing While When It is Streaming from RTSP Server

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I am using a proprietary RTSP server (I don't have access to the source code) running on a Linaro based embedded system. I am connecting to the device using WiFi and use VLC player to watch the stream. Every often, VLC player's window resizes to different sizes.

Is this a normal behavior in RTSP stream (resizing the video)?

-If yes, what is causing this change? Is it my WiFi bandwidth?

-If not, what are the suggested steps to find the root cause of this problem.

Thank you

Ahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a normal behavior in RTSP stream (resizing the video)?

Yes, the RTSP DESCRIBE Request should give info about the resolution. (See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7891517/693052))

> -If yes, what is causing this change? Is it my WiFi bandwidth?

Most probably not. However I guess more info would be needed on your bandwidth and network setup.

> -If not, what are the suggested steps to find the root cause of this problem.

**Option 1:** Try to **disable** (uncheck) VLC's preference to resize the interface to native video size, and see what happens.

[image: VLC Preferences - main window]

Also see the following post over at [superuser discussing about automatic resizing options](https://superuser.com/q/368743/311059)

**Option 2:** Enable VLC's verbose mode (console log) and see what errors or messages come up. This often helps, and points into new directions to look for solutions.

**Option 3:** It could be a problem with how information is encoded in the stream concerning the resolution. You would need to get in touch with the vendor of your RTSP server software in order to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Open the VLC player press (Ctrl + P) or go to
Tools -> Prefrences -> Interface  (look for below options)

Integrated video in interface [Check]

Resize interface to video size [UnCheck]

Must close and open again the VLC player