# Parsing Rtsp response parameter  that is  sprop-parameter-sets

Tags: h.264, rtsp, rtsp-client

I just get the response from RTSP DESCRIBE request.[ For H264 stream]

```
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42A01E;packetization-mode=1;
sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAKOkAoAQNgPsgAAADACAAAAMDwWIEJQ==,aM44gA==
```

For the

> **sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAKOkAoAQNgPsgAAADACAAAAMDwWIEJQ==,aM44gA==**

The RFC 3984 Section 8.1  says that it is [page 45]

> The value of the parameter is the base64

But using an online  Base64 Converter [ http://coderstoolbox.net/string/]  i get no meaningfull result from that string...

What  am i doing wrong? How to parse it to get meaningfull info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get a *human-readable* result by base64 decoding it. You still need to decode the H.264 sequence parameter set. It seems like you didn't see the link I posted in the other answer, so here it is again: [Fetching the dimensions of a H264Video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream)

Comment: You will end up realizing that it is the quick way.

Comment: I realize it but i stuck at ScalingList4x4[], UseDefaultScalingMatrix4x4Flag[] ,UseDefaultScalingMatrix8x8Flag[] array data structures...What are they? Defined where?