# H.264 stream header

Tags: video, hex, h.264

I have corrupted video stream with this header / parameters in the beginning.

```
00 00 00 01 67 64 00 1E AC D9 40 B0 33 FB C0 44  
00 00 03 00 04 00 00 03 00 C8 3C 58 B6 58 00 00  
00 01 68 EB EC B2 2C
```

I’m trying to figure out the actual values, but all I have guessed is that

```
67 – AVC / H264 
64 00 - High Profile
1E – Level 30 (in decimal)
```

Does anybody know what other bytes stand for?

At least, how to calculate video dimensions (Width x Height). I thought it should be decimal numbers but apparently it’s not.  Or am I all wrong and it doesn’t work this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find answers here:

- [How to decode sprop-parameter-sets in a H264 SDP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378609/how-to-decode-sprop-parameter-sets-in-a-h264-sdp)
- [Parsing Rtsp response parameter  that is  sprop-parameter-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900091/parsing-rtsp-response-parameter-that-is-sprop-parameter-sets)
- [Fetching the dimensions of a H264Video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream)

Your data decodes like this:

**Sequence Parameter Set**

```
profile_idc 100 
constraint_set0_flag 0 
constraint_set1_flag 0 
constraint_set2_flag 0 
constraint_set3_flag 0 
level_idc 30 
seq_parameter_set_id 0 
chroma_format_idc 1 
// ... 
num_ref_frames 4 
gaps_in_frame_num_value_allowed_flag 0 
pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 43 
pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 24 
frame_mbs_only_flag 1 
direct_8x8_inference_flag 1 
frame_cropping_flag 1 
frame_crop_left_offset 0 
frame_crop_right_offset 0 
frame_crop_top_offset 0 
frame_crop_bottom_offset 2 
vui_parameters_present_flag 1 
// ...
```

**Picture Parameter Set**

```
pic_parameter_set_id 0 
seq_parameter_set_id 0 
entropy_coding_mode_flag 1 
num_slice_groups_minus1 0 
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.
I didn’t even imagine how complicated H.264 could be.
I have to re-re-read all your answers on the subject to get closer to fully understand it.
(so I got my dimensions 704x396)
Thanks again, you seem to be an expert.

Answer (score 0):

If frame_cropping_flag is 1, to get the dimensions you do:

```
width = ((pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 +1)*16) - frame_crop_left_offset*2 - frame_crop_right_offset*2;
height= ((2 - frame_mbs_only_flag)* (pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 +1) * 16) - (frame_crop_top_offset * 2) - (frame_crop_bottom_offset * 2)
```