# H264 stream incorrect height [8 pixels taller]

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, mpeg-4, mpeg-2

I get `h264 stream` from an ip camera using RTSP protocol. I parse h264 `seq_parameter_data` based on the answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream], and for some ip cameras, the height value is `exactly 8 pixels bigger` than the real height.

Why it may happen? And how to fix it?

**PS:**
In my search, i found that... Maybe this might be my problem.

> "MPEG2 and MPEG4 require frame sizes to be multiples of 16 pixels
>   because macroblocks are 16x16 pixels" Every MPEG2 video ever encoded
>   as 1080 actually has 1088 lines encoded because 1080 is not evenly
>   divided by 16. The industry standard is to set the last 8 lines of the
>   frame to black. Then, the display device is expected to throw away the
>   last 8 pixels and not display them"
>   [Answer 6](http://www.kdenlive.org/forum/canon-eos-550d-clip-properties-1088)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame height is likely to be indicated by amount of 16 px blocks (e.g. 1088 pixels) + `frame_crop_*_offset` values adjust it to correct height (e.g. 1080 pixels). And you are missing the cropping.

Comment: So I should extract frame_crop_*_offset from height value?

Comment: You should obtain full frame size and adjust (reduce) it using provided cropping information.