# In mpeg-4 part 10, is the video resolution stored in a header in the video codecs or within each frame?

Tags: vlc, mpeg-4

In mpeg-4 part 10 (AVC), is the video resolution stored in a header in the video codecs or within each frame, so that each frame can have its own resolution?

If both, which of either does main stream video players as VLC take in account when playbacking?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use the Sequence Parameter Set (SPS) to determine the frame size. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774212/how-to-calculate-video-dimensions-using-sps-pps-information-in-h-264-stream