# Cannot parse Width/Height in AVC SPS

Tags: parsing, video, video-streaming, h.264, video-processing

Here is the information which I have parsed out of an avcC atom in an mp4 container
The avc extradata Conforms with ISO/IEC 14496-15:2004(E) 5.2.4.1.1

```
> 0x01 0x42 0x00 0x1E 0xFF 0xE1 0x00 0x0E

Configuration Version: 1   u(8)<br>
AVCProfileIndication:  66  u(8)<br>
profile_compatability: 0   u(8)<br> 
AVCLevelIndication:    30  u(8)<br> 
bit(6) reserved = '111111' b   <br>
unsigned int (2) lengthSizeMinusOne = '11' <br> 
bit(3) reseved = '111' <br>
unsigned int (5) numOfSequenceParameterSets = 1 <br>
unsigned int (16) sequenceParameterSetLength = 14 <br>
SPS
> 0x67 0x42 0x00 0x1E 0x8D 0x68 0x6E 0x03 0xDA 0x6A 0x0C 0x02 0x0C 0x04 <br>

avC data Continued
> 0x01 0x00 0x04 <br>

unsigned int (8) numOfPictureParameterSets: 1 <br>
unsigned int (16) pictureParameterSetLength: 4 <br>
PPS <br>
>0x68 0xCE 0x74 0xC8
```

The contents of the SPS appears to give incorrect results regarding `pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 (5)` and I do not believe there are any `emulation_3_byte` preventions. Am I missing something obvious? I am parsing the SPS according to ISO/IEC 14496-10:2004(E) which is the same SPS parsing information found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream).

Answer (score 0):

Image is 96x16 ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream))

#### Sequence Parameter Set

```
profile_idc 66 
constraint_set0_flag 0 
constraint_set1_flag 0 
constraint_set2_flag 0 
constraint_set3_flag 0 
level_idc 30 
seq_parameter_set_id 0 
// ... 
num_ref_frames 1 
gaps_in_frame_num_value_allowed_flag 0 
pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 5 
pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 0 
frame_mbs_only_flag 1 
direct_8x8_inference_flag 1 
frame_cropping_flag 0 
vui_parameters_present_flag 0 
// ...
```

#### Picture Parameter Set

```
pic_parameter_set_id 0 
seq_parameter_set_id 0 
entropy_coding_mode_flag 0 
num_slice_groups_minus1 0 
// ...
```