# HEVC: Fetching the input width and height from input bin stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, hevc, h.265

I have created an elementary bin stream using `HM-12.0` reference code. So the out put is an HEVC encoded bin stream (say input.bin).

I have a task which involves reading the header of this elementary stream. That is i need to fetch information such a the stream width, height etc. from the `input.bin` file.

After seeing a lots of streams, i can conclude that all these bin streams starts from the sequence:

```
00 00 00 01
```

So whenever i see this sequence in any bin stream, i can say that this stream has to be decoded by HEVC decoder.

Further if i want to fetch the width, height, fps etc. from the input.bin (like ff_raw_video_read_header function in ffmpeg), that are the steps need to be performed to fetch this information?

I have gone through the parsing section of the HEVC draft, but its very complicated for my level in video domain. Can anyone suggest a simple way to fetch the required information from the encoded bin file?

Any suggestions will be really helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI 00000001 is the start code defined in Annex B of the H.264 standard. Just looking at the start code does not tell you what kind of stream you are dealing with i.e. H.264 or H.265.

Comment: Dear @Zax, how do you parse the bitstream file? Do you have any code available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen you ask a lot of question about video lately. When it comes to video; There is no such thing as a "simple way".

Here is the AVC answer. [Fetching the dimensions of a H264Video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream)

First off, the fps, is usually not encoded in the ES. That is a container level thing. There is a place for in the AVC/HEVC, but you should not count on it being filled in.

You have already found start code. For the record a start code is 2 or more 00 followed but a 01 (it is not always 00 00 00 01, it can be 00 00 01, 00 00 00 00 01, etc.) If this sequence ever shows up in a NALU naturally, it must be escaped. So, when encoding a 00 00 01 within a NALU payload will be changed to 00 00 03 01. I mention this, because if you encounter this sequence while parsing, you must ignore the presence of the `emulation prevention` byte (03). The ES with the `emulation prevention` bytes removed is called the Raw Byte Sequence Payload (rbsp).

The first two bytes after the start code has the nal_unit_header. the type is stored bits 1-6 `( ( NALU[0] >> 1 ) & 0x3F )`. The resolution is stores in the SPS_NUT, which is 33. Once you have the SPS, you can parse it.

This brings us to exponential golomb encoding. basically a `exponential golomb encoded` integer (abbreviated `ue` of unsigned, or `se` for signed) is a variable length integer. To decode you count leading zeros. This count will tell you the length of the integer in bits. Next you read that many bits and subtract 1 to get your integer. The signed variant is the same, except the last bit is the sign bit for example:

```
1     = 0 =  0
010   = 1 =  1
011   = 2 = -1
00100 = 3 =  2
00101 = 4 = -2
```

Next parse the sps using the table in 7.3.2.2 of the Rec. ITU-T H.265 (04/2013) (page 33)

And finely you can calculate the detentions from pic_width_in_luma_samples pic_height_in_luma_samples and conformance_window paramaters.

Comment: Its a really good explanation. Where do you get to read these things apart from the HEVC standard draft? Please provide links to some website or some materials. It shall be useful to me as well as to anyone referring to this site.

Comment: Years of experience in video. Its really difficult to find all this information. Books, internet, ITU docs, and reverse engineering is where I learn things.

Comment: The best place to start is really the reference-codec. Load the debug-variant in a debugger and start stepping the code...

Comment: is following correct: `if(conformance_window_flag) width-to-display=pic_width_in_luma_samples-(conf_win_left_offset+conf_win_right_offset)` ?

Comment: Does `def_disp_win_left_offset` and `def_disp_win_right_offset` from vui affect displayed-width ?

Answer (score 0):

szatmary nailed it. I wanted to clarify how to calculate the frame size (at least the width, read the document for the height. Just do it) from the SPS as it can be confusing (unless you actually spend the time to read the whole document, just do it).

```
if (chroma_format_idc == 1) 
    SubWidthC = 2
else 
    SubWidthC = 1

if(conformance_window_flag)
    width-to-display = pic_width_in_luma_samples - ((conf_win_left_offset + conf_win_right_offset) * SubWidthC);
```