# H264 getting frame height and width from sequence parameter set (SPS) NAL unit

Tags: height, width, frame, resolution, h.264

I've been trying to find out how to calculate width a height from SPS nal unit. I have H264 video which has these parameters

```
h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20 fps, 20 tbr, 1200k tbn, 40 tbc
```

I've been searching for a formula which would calculate width (1280) and height (720) but haven't found any which would help me. Right now I'm using [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream) and it works for most H264 streams but in this case height and width is 80x48

```
if(frame_cropping_flag) {
    width = ((pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 +1)*16) - frame_crop_left_offset*2 - frame_crop_right_offset*2;
    height= ((2 - frame_mbs_only_flag)* (pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 +1) * 16) - (frame_crop_top_offset * 2) - (frame_crop_bottom_offset * 2);
}
else {
    width = ((pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 +1)*16);
    height= ((2 - frame_mbs_only_flag)* (pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 +1) * 16);
}
```

here is SPS as base64

```
Z2QAKa2EBUViuKxUdCAqKxXFYqOhAVFYrisVHQgKisVxWKjoQFRWK4rFR0ICorFcVio6ECSFITk8nyfk/k/J8nm5s00IEkKQnJ5Pk/J/J+T5PNzZprQCgC3YCqQAAAMB4AAASwGBAAH0AAADAjKAve+F4RCNQA==
```

here is SPS that I've parsed:

```
======= SPS =======
 profile_idc : 100
 constraint_set0_flag : 0
 constraint_set1_flag : 0
 constraint_set2_flag : 0
 constraint_set3_flag : 0
 constraint_set4_flag : 0
 constraint_set5_flag : 0
 reserved_zero_2bits : 0
 level_idc : 41
 seq_parameter_set_id : 0
 chroma_format_idc : 1
 separate_colour_plane_flag : 0
 bit_depth_luma_minus8 : 0
 bit_depth_chroma_minus8 : 0
 qpprime_y_zero_transform_bypass_flag : 0
 seq_scaling_matrix_present_flag : 1
 log2_max_frame_num_minus4 : 41
 pic_order_cnt_type : 4
   log2_max_pic_order_cnt_lsb_minus4 : 0
   delta_pic_order_always_zero_flag : 0
   offset_for_non_ref_pic : 0
   offset_for_top_to_bottom_field : 0
   num_ref_frames_in_pic_order_cnt_cycle : 0
 num_ref_frames : 2
 gaps_in_frame_num_value_allowed_flag : 0
 pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 : 4
 pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 : 2
 frame_mbs_only_flag : 1
 mb_adaptive_frame_field_flag : 0
 direct_8x8_inference_flag : 0
 frame_cropping_flag : 0
   frame_crop_left_offset : 0
   frame_crop_right_offset : 0
   frame_crop_top_offset : 0
   frame_crop_bottom_offset : 0
 vui_parameters_present_flag : 0
=== VUI ===
 aspect_ratio_info_present_flag : 0
   aspect_ratio_idc : 0
     sar_width : 0
     sar_height : 0
 overscan_info_present_flag : 0
   overscan_appropriate_flag : 0
 video_signal_type_present_flag : 0
   video_format : 0
   video_full_range_flag : 0
   colour_description_present_flag : 0
     colour_primaries : 0
   transfer_characteristics : 0
   matrix_coefficients : 0
 chroma_loc_info_present_flag : 0
   chroma_sample_loc_type_top_field : 0
   chroma_sample_loc_type_bottom_field : 0
 timing_info_present_flag : 0
   num_units_in_tick : 0
   time_scale : 0
   fixed_frame_rate_flag : 0
 nal_hrd_parameters_present_flag : 0
 vcl_hrd_parameters_present_flag : 0
   low_delay_hrd_flag : 0
 pic_struct_present_flag : 0
 bitstream_restriction_flag : 0
   motion_vectors_over_pic_boundaries_flag : 0
   max_bytes_per_pic_denom : 0
   max_bits_per_mb_denom : 0
   log2_max_mv_length_horizontal : 0
   log2_max_mv_length_vertical : 0
   num_reorder_frames : 0
   max_dec_frame_buffering : 0
=== HRD ===
 cpb_cnt_minus1 : 0
 bit_rate_scale : 0
 cpb_size_scale : 0
   bit_rate_value_minus1[0] : 0
   cpb_size_value_minus1[0] : 0
   cbr_flag[0] : 0
 initial_cpb_removal_delay_length_minus1 : 0
 cpb_removal_delay_length_minus1 : 0
 dpb_output_delay_length_minus1 : 0
 time_offset_length : 0
```

I guess it has something to do with luma and chroma macroblocks size I've been able to calculate SubWidthC\SubHeightC and MbWidthC\MbHeightC. But I'm still confused what to do next.

Comment: are you using libh264butstream to parse?

Comment: No where can I find it?

Comment: Then what is generating that output? Did you write your own parser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hello first of all you are parsing SPS incorrectly so you need to fix that. If you parse it correctly then you will have

```
pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 : 79
pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 : 44
frame_mbs_only_flag : 1
frame_cropping_flag : 0
```

If you calculate width and height using your formula then you will actualy have 1280x720

Anyway you should calculate height and width using SubWidth and SubHeight as follows:

```
int SubWidthC;
int SubHeightC;

if (sps->chroma_format_idc == 0 && sps->separate_colour_plane_flag == 0) { //monochrome
    SubWidthC = SubHeightC = 0;
}
else if (sps->chroma_format_idc == 1 && sps->separate_colour_plane_flag == 0) { //4:2:0 
    SubWidthC = SubHeightC = 2;
}
else if (sps->chroma_format_idc == 2 && sps->separate_colour_plane_flag == 0) { //4:2:2 
    SubWidthC = 2;
    SubHeightC = 1;
}
else if (sps->chroma_format_idc == 3) { //4:4:4
    if (sps->separate_colour_plane_flag == 0) {
        SubWidthC = SubHeightC = 1;
    }
    else if (sps->separate_colour_plane_flag == 1) {
        SubWidthC = SubHeightC = 0;
    }
}

int PicWidthInMbs = sps->pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 + 1;

int PicHeightInMapUnits = sps->pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 + 1;
int FrameHeightInMbs = (2 - sps->frame_mbs_only_flag) * PicHeightInMapUnits;

int crop_left = 0;
int crop_right = 0;
int crop_top = 0;
int crop_bottom = 0;

if (sps->frame_cropping_flag) {
    crop_left = sps->frame_crop_left_offset;
    crop_right = sps->frame_crop_right_offset;
    crop_top = sps->frame_crop_top_offset;
    crop_bottom = sps->frame_crop_bottom_offset;
}

int width = PicWidthInMbs * 16 - SubWidthC * (crop_left + crop_right);
int height = FrameHeightInMbs * 16 - SubHeightC * (2 - sps->frame_mbs_only_flag) * (crop_top + crop_bottom);
```

Comment: Is it correct that with 4:4:4 and separate_color_plane_flag==1, the value of crop_left doesn't matter, because SubWidthC becomes 0?

Answer (score 1):

we now have an H.264 SPS parser in librem:

https://github.com/creytiv/rem/blob/master/include/rem_h264.h#L52

it can be used like this, to extract the resolution:

```
    struct h264_sps sps;
    struct vidsz vidsz;

    h264_sps_decode(&sps, buf, len);

    h264_sps_resolution(&sps, vidsz);

    printf("resolution: %u x %u\n", vidsz.w, vidsz.h);
```

Comment: Cool, that works. Now their way of getting one bit at a time... but for what I'm doing it's not an issue.