# h264 vui,time_scale,time_tick from sps

Tags: video, h.264, frame-rate

I use ffmpeg to send the RTP of mp4 (only video) to my RTP Server.
And I could retrieve the RTP packet and get the 67 42 ... (sps).

But I want to calculate the frame rate from the sps(using vui(if flag == 1), time_tick and time_scale).

Are there any source code(such as open source) could resolve the sps ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2):

- [H.264 specification](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-201402-S/en), which describes the bitstream including SPS, VUI information etc.
- [H.264 VUI parsing code](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/blob/master/src/H264StructReader.cpp#L32) in GraphStudioNext application source code
- [Fetching the dimensions of a H264Video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394874/fetching-the-dimensions-of-a-h264video-stream/6477652#6477652) - on parsing H.264 parameter sets

Comment: Hi thank for your help
Now I can get the VUI_flag, but I could not fetch the time_scale and tick.
Because there are some variable bits when I parse the bits such as bit_depth_luma_minus8(ue(v)) , bit_depth_chroma_minus8(ue(v)), offset_for_ref_frame(se(v)) and so on.

Comment: [Code](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/blob/master/src/H264StructReader.cpp#L76) behind link 2 above succeeds in parsing this variable length data.